# How best to manage TYPO3 installations using git?

Tags: git, content-management-system, typo3, web-deployment

Hello I have been meaning to get around to this for a while now, but I would like to use git to maintain some typo3 development sites. I did some digging around and the most informative ([chromium translated site](http://www.chmuul.net/2010/02/saubere-git-repositories-fur-typo3-projekte/)) info on the subject isn't clear but did make me think. I'd like to know how to setup a git managed repo and if there are some/other folders that I should ignore when setting up the repo, what I should be wary of, best practices, etc. I have decided that with each version, a db dump would be done separately which corresponds with the milestone because as of now I'm not sure how to deal with this aspect of CMS versioning.

Comment: Link went dead, probably out of date anyway, but here is what is left: http://web.archive.org/web/20130706031806/http://www.chmuul.net/2010/02/saubere-git-repositories-fur-typo3-projekte

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's is typical `.gitignore`

```
/fileadmin/user_upload/
/fileadmin/_temp_/

/uploads/

/typo3conf/temp_CACHED*
/typo3conf/temp_fieldInfo.php
/typo3conf/localconf_local.php

/typo3/
/t3lib/
/typo3temp/
```

Keep in mind that when using `TYPO3` with `git` you should not install any extension on the remote with `Extension Manager`!

Instead import ext locally, install it locally and then commit and push ext's files and modified `localconf.php` to remote server.

At the end of the `localconf.php` include `localconf_local.php` (ignored)

```
@include('localconf_local.php');
```

It will allow to override ie. credentials for DB, or custom `ImageMagick` path without changing the original `localconf.php`. Each dev in the team of course writes his own values to `localconf_local.php`.

Typical TYPO3 folders ignored in `.gitignore` should be created manually at each instance ie.

`typo3temp`

`fileadmin/user_upload`

Of course you need also download TYPO3 sorces (`typo3`, `t3lib` folders) - there is no bigger sense to keep them under version control.

Other things, like `uploads` should be downloaded manually from the remote, so it's best to write a script which will pack it and every developer will have possibility to download it with some link. You can't add this to git repo as these files are just created while creating the content element, so if you won't ignore them you risk a huge merging conflict soon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to both of you. I'll accept an answer once I have successfully implemented this in a few days time.

Comment: You should take care that e.g. "/.git/config" is not exposed publicly via HTTP (i made it a habit to put typo3 stuff in a /public/ subfolder). edit: haha, chmuul.net is my blog :) If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: Additional note: I'll see if I can rewrite the tutorial more detailed, translated to english and with my capistrano receipt.

Comment: the `@include('localconf_local.php');` part is no longer valid/possible since v6.0 - but there is a better (official) way now, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350213/typo3-ver-6-x-additional-configuration-a-k-a-localconf-local-php

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to add some aspects to biesiors very good answer: From my experience, the best strategy is to put `fileadmin/` and `typo3conf/` under version control, and nothing else at first. If you use extensions, you will therefore use the latest version from the TER repository only. Extension configuration (typoscript setup, locallang values) will be placed in external files within fileadmin/. Example folder structure:

```
fileadmin/
- css/
- images/
- javascript/
- scripts/
- templates/
- - html/
- - templavoila/
- - typoscript/
- - xml/
```

Do not store any typoscript information in the database - it cannot be versioned from there.

Place `.gitignore` where needed. We also ignore `typo3conf/ext/` and `typo3conf/l10n/`. Why? If we write our own extensions (or modify existing ones), we add the `typo3conf/ext/my_extensionname/` to another repository. This way, the extension itself can be well  maintained, especially if used in multiple projects. And unchanged extensions do not need to be versioned at all.

Follow the `@include('localconf_local.php');` suggestion - this is good practice.

This setup adds a higher demand on coding discipline, but you will be rewarded! We have been successfully working like that for more then 12 projects now in a team of two.

Comment: We are currently storing the entire ext/ directory in a git repository. What technique are you using to get all the extensions in the right place from the repositories within an automated deployment proces? Git submodules seem really inflexible and a lot of administrative overhead. Using the git subtree technique you could always extract the extension to a seperate repository if you wanted to. I think storing all the extensions in different repositories is more trouble than it's worth. Please tell me about your arguments for doing this.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding: We only include the extensions we are developing ourselves, in most projects only one or two. All the other extensions are ignored by the `typo3conf/ext/` in `.gitignore`