# TYPO3 ver. 6.x - additional configuration a.k.a. `localconf_local.php`

Tags: typo3, configuration-files, typo3-6.2.x

#### What we need

In TYPO3 ver. 4.x we used to include additional configuration file for overwriting some settings (ie. DB credentials) by adding the include statement at the end of the `localconf.php`:

```
@include_once('localconf_local.php');
```

Thanks to this trick it is possible for an example keep separate database settings or IM paths individual for each developer as we can just ignore our 'local' files from the git repository.

#### What's the problem

Unfortunately in TYPO3 ver. 6.x that approach requires manual changes of the `LocalConfiguration.php` to overwrite the values before the `return` statement, what's more after each operation in Install Tool (or Extension Manager) the file is completely to original syntax (so we need to change it again and again...

#### Question

Have you guys any workaround for this? Or this is just... impossible to do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Got it! :)

The answer is: `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` if this file exists it's included automatically, to overwrite some values we need to use well-known syntax ie.:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['database'] = 'my_local_database';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['host']     = 'localhost';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['username'] = 'username';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['password'] = 'mypassword';
?>
```

From ["What's new" SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/rafalbrzeski/typo3-60-whats-new) (page 33)

Comment: Also listed on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/In-depth/TheDistributionsInDetail/Index.html

Comment: @cweiske, that link has gone stale. Currently this seems to be the page you want to link to: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/In-depth/ThePackageInDetail/Index.html

Comment: The configuration for DB settings slightly changed in TYPO3 9.5.x due to changed DB configuration: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections']['Default'][...]`. For the correct fields have a look into the `LocalConfiguration.php`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your own answer pay attention to a fact, that from 6.0 you shouldn't access TYPO3_CONF_VARS directly in your extension, but by **getLocalConfigurationValueByPath**('BE/loginSecurityLevel') and **setLocalConfigurationValueByPath**('BE/loginSecurityLevel', 'rsa') in `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\ConfigurationManager` class.

Taken from same ["What's new" SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/rafalbrzeski/typo3-60-whats-new) page 35.

UPDATE 15.06.15: Page 35 was included by accident to slides. Since TYPO3 6.2 ConfigurationManager is marked @internal. So, you **shouldn't use ConfigurationManager** in your own code. [Details](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/53417)

Comment: But according to a [bug report](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/60650) the methods you mentioned aren't meant to be used in the AdditionalConfiguration.php file or outside of the core.

Comment: @zauni Thank you for pointing out. I've updated my answer, so others know, taht this solution shouldn't be used.